# Setting the font-family of the input field of a react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

So I'm trying to style the input field of a react-select component. Unfortunately, the font-family is being overwritten by the standard input element since the styles are being applied to the wrapper div and not the input field itself.

```
input: () => ({
  fontFamily: `${theme.fonts.tabs.family} !important`,
  fontWeight: theme.fonts.tabs.weight,
  fontSize: 18,
  color: theme.colors.secondary,
  height: 24
}),
```

How would I go about changing the fontFamily without using class names?

What this code produces
[image: What this code produces]
What I want
[image: What I want]

Comment: which version of react-select are you using ?

Answer (score 12):

React-Select renders the html **`input`** element inside the `div` that gets the class property that you assign when you use this input component styles.

So to extend your attempt, just add a child selector on your styles object, targeting that input.

```js
input: () => ({
  fontFamily: `${theme.fonts.tabs.family}`,
  '& input': {
    font: 'inherit',
  },
}),
```

That way the rendered `input` inherits the font style from the div that receives the generated `*-Input` class.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following style-in-JS `props`:

```
control: base => ({
    ...base,
    fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
  })
```

No need to use `!important` declaration.

**EDIT**

It seems to have an issue for the `input` and it does not render proper `fontSize` so have a complete experience you can add a `className` on your select like this:

```
<Select className="select" styles={styles} options={options} />
```

and apply the following CSS:

```
.select input {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/10r714wp0l).

Comment: Sorry @PennyPang but you will have to provide a deeper example of your code because as you can see on the live example I've just added it's working well.

Comment: Hi @Laura, it was the user input when I start to type, turned out not to be Times New Roman. Is there a way to have the user input typing as the same font too?

Comment: @PennyPang I did some update to have the same font in the user input. You can't use CSS-in-Js props so I guess you could open an issue on github